# Save a class into a binary file - Python

Tags: python, file, class, binary, save

I'm aware that saving a class into a binary file in c++ is possible using:

```
file.write(Class_variable, size_of_class, amount_of_saves, file_where_to_save)
```

or something similar, and I wanted to use that in python in order to make it easier to write and read lots of data.

I've tried to do this:

```
def Save_Game(player, room):
    address = 'Saves/player'

    file = open(address, 'wb')
    file.write(player)

    address = 'Saves/room'

    file = open(address, 'wb')
    file.write(room)
```

Room and player being class_objects. But it says:

```
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not PlayerMarty
```

What can I do?

Comment: Use picke which is used for serialization and de-serialization of python objects. The objects are saved/loaded as pickle formats

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`pickle` is what you need. The `pickle` module implements a fundamental, but powerful algorithm for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. This is an example

```
import pickle

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def display(self):
        print(self.name)

my = MyClass("someone")
pickle.dump(my, open("myobject", "wb"))
me = pickle.load(open("myobject", "rb"))
me.display()
```

Comment: Curious - could you make `save` a function of class `MyClass`? If so, what you pass in lieu of `my`? I tried with `self`, but got a TypeError.

Comment: @kuanb you can create a static method (or another helper function for the save. In fact you can create "save" and "load" method of `MyClass`.

Comment: But the file produced by pickle is a text file, not binary!

Answer (score 5):

You *can* get at the bytes of Python objects to save & restore them like that, but it's not easy to do directly. However, the standard [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html) module simplifies the process enormously.